# Select-Object has different behavior using piping vs. -InputObject

Tags: powershell

can someone shed light on why example 2 does not have the same result as example 1? I would think that $a and $b2 should be the same. $b2 is null! I am writing a script where using the method in example 2 is preferable.

example 1:

```
$a = Get-Content $some_text_file | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

example 2:

```
$b1 = Get-Content $some_text_file
$b2 = Select-Object -InputObject $b1 -Skip 1
```

edit: using this syntax gets me where I need to be.

```
$b1 = Get-Content $file
$b2 = $b1 | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

Comment: from the help for that cmdlet >>> `When you use the InputObject parameter with Select-Object , instead of piping command results to Select-Object , the InputObject value-even if the value is a collection that is the result of a command, such as "-InputObject (Get-Process)"-is treated as a single object.` <<<

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: Yep, when piping in, a process block runs on each one.  But when passed as a parameter, unless the author wrote an extra foreach loop, it will only run over it once.

Comment: same problem... Thanks Lee...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064839/select-object-has-different-behavior-using-piping-vs-inputobject#comment100654963_57064839), this is expected behavior

> can someone shed light on why

This has to do with how cmdlets execute in the pipeline.

As you might know, the core functionality of a [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet?view=pscore-6.2.0) is made up of three methods:

- [`BeginProcessing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.beginprocessing?view=pscore-6.2.0)
- [`ProcessRecord()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.processrecord?view=pscore-6.2.0)
- [`EndProcessing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.endprocessing?view=pscore-6.2.0)

*(the `begin`/`process`/`end` blocks in an advanced function correspond to these).

`BeginProcessing()` and `EndProcessing()` are always executed *exactly once*. How many times `ProcessRecord()` execute depend on whether it's the first command in a pipeline or not.

When a cmdlet occurs as the first element in a pipeline (ie. there are no `|` sign to the left of it), `ProcessRecord()` executes *once*.

When a cmdlet receives input from an upstream command in its pipeline, however, `ProcessRecord()` is run *once for each input item* coming in through the pipeline.

With this in mind, please consider this simplified version of `Select-Object`:

```
function Select-FakeObject {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]]$InputObject,

        [Parameter()]
        [int]$Skip = 0
    )

    begin {
        $skipped = 0
    }

    process {
        if($skipped -lt $Skip){
            $skipped++
            Write-Host "Skipping $InputObject"
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "Selecting $InputObject"
            Write-Output $InputObject
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's try both scenarios with this dummy function:

```
PS C:\> $a = 1,2,3
PS C:\> $b1 = $a |Select-FakeObject -Skip 1
```

We'll see that PowerShell indeed calls the `process` block *once per input item*:

```
Skipping 1
Selecting 2
Selecting 3
```

whereas if we pass the object like in your second example:

```
PS C:\> $a = 1,2,3
PS C:\> $b2 = Select-FakeObject -Skip 1
Skipping 1 2 3
```

We now see that the `process` block only executes once, over all of `$a` rather than the individual items.

Comment: Some above average commands can process an array passed to a parameter, like `get-process -name explorer,notepad`.

Comment: @js2010 I'm not saying "you can't", I'm trying to explain why `Select-Object` _doesn't_